# Parse url structure by regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have one **`URL`** pattern :

`product/[cat]/[page].[ext]`

**product/category/page.html**

**product/page.html**

But my **Regular Expression** does not work properly :

```
^product\/([\w\d\.\-_\s\'\"\(\)\[\]\؀-\ۿ](?!.*\.html))*\/([\w\d\.\-_\s\'\"\(\)\[\]\؀-\ۿ]+\.html+)*\/?$
```

I want by one **`regEx`** pattern detect url and it parameters

I use **`match`** function in javascript

**EDIT :**

**my route pattern :**

```
product/cat?/page.html?
```

I want make `regEx` by this pattern

`?` in this pattern means this section is optional

For example :

**`makeRegEx('product/cat?/page.html?')`**

**result:**

```
^product\/([\w\d\.\-_\s\'\"\(\)\[\]\؀-\ۿ](?!.*\.html))*\/([\w\d\.\-_\s\'\"\(\)\[\]\؀-\ۿ]+\.html+)*\/?$
```

**when route :** `product/computer/ram.html`

regular expression detect :

`cat = computer`

`page = ram.html`

Comment: `"product/cat/page.html".split(/[./]/)`

Comment: What are these strange characters "ۿ"? Also what is the goal of the regex? check if it is a particular route?

Comment: @Kaddath  \u0600-\u06FF,   Yes check url by pattern list for route to destination

Comment: @Andreas regular expression It's faster

Comment: _"regular expression It's faster"_ - That's just an opinion

Answer (score 0):

Is this regular expression solving your problem ?

```
^product\/([a-zA-Z]+)\/*([a-zA-Z]+)\.([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Try some cases on my [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SV4KwJ/1)

Comment: My question is edited, I want to make regEx for myself pattern

Answer (score 0):

this is function to generate regression solved your problem.

```js
function makeRegEx(route, url) {
    let pattern = new RegExp('(:([a-z]+))(\\??)', 'g');
    let match = route.match(pattern);
    let route_regex = route.replace(/\//g, '\\/').replace(/\./g, '(\\.*)');
    for(let params of match) {
        let required = params.includes('?') ? '*' : '+';
        route_regex = route_regex.replace(params, '([a-z_\\-]'+required+')')
    }
    let params_match = url.match(route_regex);
    let map_params;
    if (params_match) {
        map_params = match.map((item, key) => { return {param: item, value: params_match[key + 1]} });
    } else {
        map_params = 'missing required params';
    }

    return {
        url, route, route_regex, map_params
    }

}
// test cases:
console.log(makeRegEx('product/:cat/:page.html', 'product//.html'));
console.log(makeRegEx('product/:cat/:page.html', 'product/computer/.html'));
console.log(makeRegEx('product/:cat/:page.html', 'product/computer/cpu.html'));

console.log(makeRegEx('product/:cat/:page?.html', 'product//cpu.html'));
console.log(makeRegEx('product/:cat/:page?.html', 'product/computer/.html'));
console.log(makeRegEx('product/:cat/:page?.html', 'product/computer/cpu.html'));

console.log(makeRegEx('product/:cat/:page.:type', 'product/computer/.html'));
console.log(makeRegEx('product/:cat/:page.:type', 'product//.html'));
console.log(makeRegEx('product/:cat/:page.:type', 'product/computer/cpu.html'));

console.log(makeRegEx('product/:cat/:page.:type?', 'product/computer/cpu'));
console.log(makeRegEx('product/:cat/:page.:type?', 'product/computer/cpu.html'));
```

Comment: Thank you lê-phi, But if :cat is optional what's happened?