# regular expression to detect strings structure

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to find a regular expression that does not allow strings containing the "." character in the first section,

But next sections allowed

**For example:**

**`section1/section2`**

```
AA/BB.html

section1 : AA
section2 : BB.html


BB.html

section1: ''
section2: BB.html


AA

section1: AA
section2: ''
```

Comment: just for more clarification, your input is something like 
'section1 : AA
section2 : BB.html' and output you require something like 'AA/BB.html' 
If i understand correctly?

Comment: @freedom https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510438/parse-url-structure-by-regular-expression/62512578

Comment: @freedom https://regextester.com/?fam=117179 in the first example group1 is incorrect and this must empty

Comment: When you say, `first section` do you mean the first line containing the literal `Section 1`, the first line containing `:` or something else? In your example which lines constitute the "first section"?. In other words, you need to provide a precise definition for "section".

Comment: @CarySwoveland https://www.regextester.com/?fam=117202 in the first example, group1 is incorrect and this must empty.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
var str = "AA/BB.html";

var splited = str.split(/\//);
console.log(splited);

var filtered = splited.filter(x => !x.includes("."));
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: how to use Regular Expression and match function ??

Comment: var matched = str.split(/\//).filter(x => x.match(/\./));
console.log(matched);

Comment: empty section (section1: '') is important for me to use resulte

Comment: exactly whats your input and expected output?

Comment: `^product\/([\w\d\-_\؀-\ۿ\s\'\"\(\)\[\]][^\.html\/]*)*\/?([\w\d\-_\؀-\ۿ\s\'\"\(\)\[\]]+\.html+)+` in this case (product/BB.html) I want Group 1 : empty and Group 2 : BB.html

Comment: https://www.regextester.com/?fam=117179 in the first example  group1 is incorrect and this must empty

Comment: there are always two letters(BB) after slash?

Comment: no, this is a url structure, for example: pattern: (product/:cat/:page.html ) url(product/computer/ram.html) result : cat=computer , page=ram OR url(product/ram.html) result cat=' ' , page=ram || ram.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe this way

```js
function allowOrNot(str){
  var splited = str.split(/\//);
  for(i=0; i<splited.length; i++){
    if(splited[i].includes(".") && i != 0){
      return "not allowed";
    } 
  }
  return "allowed";
}

console.log(allowOrNot("AA.html/BB"));  //allowed
console.log(allowOrNot("AA/BB.html"));  //not allowed
```